# Cloud Messaging Firebase (Android) - как отправить push 1-му пользователю?

Tags: android, firebase, android-notification, fcm, google-cloud-messages

Только начинаю осваивать андроид. Сделал простое приложение. Зарегился в Firebase консоли, затем в Android Studio 3.1.2 нажал Tools->Firebase->Cloud Messaging. Там выполнил первый и второй пункты. Попробовал в консоли отправить сообщение "всем" - оно пришло и отобразилось в уведомлениях. Т.е. все работает и android studio все сделал за меня.
Читал разные мануалы, в т.ч. [этот](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/push-notifications-with-firebase-cloud-messaging) там немного по другому описывается, в последних версиях я как понимаю автоматом сделали.
Но вопрос теперь как отправить сообщение конкретному устройству? Для этого нужен токен.
Его я получаю успешно. В активити в **onCreate()** я добавил код:

```
 String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    // Log and toast
    String msg = "Refreshed token: " + token;
    Log.d(TAG, msg);
```

Потом копирую этот токен в консоль Firebird ставлю отправить только одному этому токену и ничего нет. Я так понимаю, чтобы получать индивидуальный пуш данный код нужно допиливать? Почему тогда пуш на всех работает?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если нужно допиливать, то не подскажите, годный и современный гайд где можно посмотреть?

P.S. С примера по ссылке пробовал скомпилировал проект, но токен не получается, да и уведомление толком не работает, уведомляет, но сам текст не выводится.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Оказывается все приходит, когда приложение в бэкграунде находится. А если в foreground, то нужно писать обработчик на отображения пуша.

Comment: Можешь дать пример обработчика?